# InvalidOperationException When using Context Injection in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

In my ASP.Net core web app, I connect to my DB using the following in startup

```cs
services.AddDbContext<TimeSheetContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureSql")));
```

This works fine until I attempt injection on my DBcontext class.

I have an interface and class that gets the logged in user

```cs
public interface IGetUserProvider
{
    string UserName {get; }
    int BranchID {get; }
}

public class GetUserProvider : IGetUserProvider
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int BranchID { get; set; }    

    public GetUserProvider(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        
        UserName = accessor.HttpContext?.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == UserName)?.Value;
        BranchID = 6108;
    }    
}
```

BranchID = 6108 will be dynamic based on UserName but for debugging I am setting it myself.

When I have these classes in the program, whenever I select a Razor Page on the web app it throws the error

> InvalidOperationException: A named connection string was used, but the name 'AzureSql' was not found in the application's configuration.

The exception is occurring at the point the context is called in the Razor Code Behind e.g.

```cs
public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            BranchHour = await _context.BranchHours
                .Include(b => b.Branch)
                .Where(d => d.BranchOpen.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)
                .OrderBy(b => b.Branch.BranchNumber)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

As I say, the code runs fine without the Injection but when it is in it claims there is no connection string called AzureSql when obviously there is. I have to assume the error is being caused by something else but I can't seem to find it.

## Edit with DB Context

```cs
public TimeSheetContext(DbContextOptions<TimeSheetContext> options, IGetUserProvider userProvider)
            : base(options)
        {
            User = userProvider.UserName;
            branchFilter = userProvider.BranchID;
            
        }
```

The reason for the injection is to be used as a global filter inside OnModelCreating

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>().HasQueryFilter(b => b.ContractorCode == branchFilter);
```

Comment: "until I attempt injection on my DBcontext class" What do you mean by this? I don't see any injection in your code

Comment: Presumably you have the connection string in your appsettings.json as {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureSql": "....."
  },
}

Comment: @Serge I may have mispoke in my usage of the term injection but I have added the part of the context code where the issue is happening.

Comment: @allan definitely there. As I say, if I don't attempt to pass userProvider data mentioned in the post, it all works with the connection.

Comment: Does your db context derived class have other public constructor?

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev the issue was a blank constructor. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by removing the blank constructor I had in the context. All credit goes to Ivan in the comments.